# Why doesn't this python 3 string handling work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why doesn't this string handling work?

When you input `"hectare"`, the full answer, it should print `"+2"`. When only `"hect"` is correct and the next 3 letters are incorrect the print should be `"+1"`.

At the moment I don't get a print when only getting `"hect"` correct.

```
answer = "hectare"
answerlen = int(len(answer)/2)

test = str(input("enter it"))


if test == answer:
print("+2")
else:
    if test == answer[0:answerlen]:
        print("+1")
```

Comment: At the moment I dont' get a print when only getting "hect" correct.

Comment: Since hectare is odd numbered, `int(7/2)` will produce 3 and `answer[0:3]` will result `hec` instead of `hect`.

Comment: @Lafexlos true, and using `//` doesn't change this. OP, you can use `math.ceil` to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing the *whole of `test`* to the start of `answer`. Instead, try:

```
if test[:answerlen] == answer[:answerlen]:
```

Note that `0` is the default start for a slice.

Also, you can simplify using integer division:

```
answerlen = len(answer) // 2
```

and `elif`

```
if test == answer:
    print("+2")
elif test[:answerlen] == answer[:answerlen]:
    print("+1")
```

and `startswith`:

```
elif answer.startswith(test[:answerlen]):
```

Comment: I'd prefer the second comparison to read: `elif answer.startswith(test[:answerlen]): ` to get rid of the clumsy second slice operation.